# Box2DWeb - Adding and Removing Body in the world

Tags: javascript, html, box2d

I have the following code in Box2D, I want to move my dynamic body to the point where the mouse is click. Also in the future i want to be able to remove the dynamic body, I am not able to find anything equivalent to world.DeleteBody(...). Please Help.

```
var world;
var   b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2
        ,   b2BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef
        ,   b2Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body
        ,   b2FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef
        ,   b2Fixture = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Fixture
        ,   b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World
        ,   b2MassData = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2MassData
        ,   b2PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape
        ,   b2CircleShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2CircleShape
        ,   b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw
        ;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var mouseX, mouseY, isMouseDown;
var bBallBody, bBallbodyDef;

function init() {
    world = new b2World(
           new b2Vec2(0, 10)    //gravity
        ,  true                 //allow sleep
    );
    setupWorld() ;
    //setup debug draw
    var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
        debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"));
        debugDraw.SetDrawScale(1.0);
        debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.3);
        debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
        debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);

    world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
    window.setInterval(update, 1000 / 60);
  };

  function setupWorld() {
      setupGround();
      addBouncingBall();
  }

  function setupGround() {
     var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
     fixDef.density = 1.0;
     fixDef.friction = 0.5;
     fixDef.restitution = 0.2;
     var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
     //create ground
     bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_staticBody;
     bodyDef.position.x = 300;
     bodyDef.position.y = 400;
     fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
     fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(290, 10);
     world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);
  }

  function addBouncingBall() {
     var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
     fixDef.density = 1.0;
     fixDef.friction = 1.0;
     fixDef.restitution = 0.1;
     var bBallbodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
     bBallbodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
     fixDef.shape = new b2CircleShape(Math.random() + 30);
     bBallbodyDef.position.x = Math.random() * 300;
     bBallbodyDef.position.y = Math.random() * 300;
     bBallBody = world.CreateBody(bBallbodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);  
     console.log(bBallBody.m_body.GetPosition().x);

  };

  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseMove, true);

  function handleMouseMove(e) {
      isMouseDown = true;
      mouseX = e.clientX;
      mouseY = e.clientY;
  };

  function update() {

     if(isMouseDown)
      {
          for (b = world.GetBodyList() ; b; b = b.GetNext()) {
              if (b.GetType() == b2Body.b2_dynamicBody) {
                   console.log(b.x, b.y);
                   b.x = 100;
                   b.y = 100;
                   }
                   }
      isMouseDown = false; 
      } 
       world.Step(1 / 60, 10, 10);
       world.DrawDebugData();
       world.ClearForces();
  };
```

Update:

Deletion of an object from the world is done as follows,

1. Create a Timer to Schdule the deletion of the object.

   ```
      window.setInterval(removeObjScheduledForRemoval, 1000/90);
   ```
2. Collect the objects to be deleted in a Array.

   ```
      var bricksScheduledForRemoval = Array();
      var index = -1;
      function removeObjScheduledForRemoval()
      {
        for(var i = 0; i <= index; i++){
       world.DestroyBody(bricksScheduledForRemoval[i]);    
       bricksScheduledForRemoval[i] = null;    
         }
    bricksScheduledForRemoval = Array();
        index = -1;
       }
   ```

The complete code is available here,
http://box2dinabox.blogspot.in/2012/07/the-completed-bananamonkey-game.html

Comment: Hey thanks, Box2DWeb seriously lack documentation, Been breaking my head over it. Figured out some of the basic workflows, have blogged about it in http://box2dinabox.blogspot.in/ . hope Someone will find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for box2dweb is nowhere near as comprehensive as it is for the original C version, so consider searching for "box2d" instead of "box2dweb". Also, looking into the [source](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/source/browse/trunk/Box2D.js) and searching for the spelling of certain methods could be helpful. Or just look into the box2d flash documentation. Basically, box2dweb has the methods `DestroyJoint` and `DestroyBody`.

For more considerations, this could be helpful: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/removing-bodies

Comment: Hey thanks, Box2DWeb seriously lack documentation, Been breaking my head over it. Figured out some of the basic workflows, have blogged about it in http://box2dinabox.blogspot.in/ . hope Someone will find it useful :)

Answer (score -2):

You can remove the body or change the static body to dynamic as this game example does.
http://pixsansar.com/box2dweb-jumping-and-puzzle-ball-level4

Box2dweb has removebody or changeBodyType option, see the source code of it.

Comment: The above linked page throws this error: ``GET http://return.uk.domainnamesales.com/return_js.php?d=pixsansar.com&s=1393187553 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT``